# handle $errors and old input with 2 forms in a single page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2.

I'm trying to have 2 similar forms in one single page, one for registering, and one for logging in.

The problem is after some validation error, i can't recognize which one of the two was submitted to place some errors display and fill the correct form with the old input.

I had the idea of trying sending an hidden variable with the forms to recognize which one of the two was used, but when i get back to the forms page i can't retrieve the old('hidden_field').

I also tried to get the path of the referer page to check if i could recognize them from it, but it doesn't work.

Any different idea for a solution??

Comment: What do you mean you cannot retrieve it? Would you please provide the view code?

Comment: @MinaAbadir it seems that if i submit an hidden input, it isn't passed again to the form with the other inputs. If i try to read it using the old() function it doesn't work

Comment: Provide the code please

Comment: @Gabz Whether you get old input back to the page or not depends on your validation method. Sharing your code would help solve the problem quickly. [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches)

Answer (score 3):

**I. Deal with old input** 
- Make 1 attribute with different name in those 2 forms. So you can use old() normally 
**II. Deal with $errors. Use named error bag** 
*- In your Controller*

```
public function postRegister(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $array_rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('url')->withErrors($validator, 'form_register');
    }
}

public function postLogin(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $array_rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('url')->withErrors($validator, 'form_login');
    }
}
```

*- In your view*

```
//Access each form's errors normally
$errors->form_login->all()
$errors->form_register->all()

// Use old input normally
old('name_register');
old('name_login');
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a suggestion in the comments, i found out i had to add a validation rule to my hidden input field in order to pass it again to the view, and get the value with the old() method.

I could use it then to recognize which one of the two forms has been used.